RealityView iOS 18 How to Move Entity Accurately using Touch Drag Gesture
With iOS 18 RealityView is so convenient replacing SceneKit creating 3d But when it comes to moving 3d Entities using 2d touch and drag I face a problem, I could not make an accurate move which like attaching the 3d Entity to my finger while drag it on the screen, it was much easier in SceneKit using project and unproject and Also in ARKit/ARView using raycast also it is very successful in VisionOS cause it is 3D Touch and I can use 3d location in gesture value but in 2d it simply not working
here is the closest I get to and it do move the 3d entity but
not responding well to the location of the finger.
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var box = Entity()

  @State var lastPanTouchPosition: CGPoint = .zero

  var body: some View {
    RealityView{ content in
        
        let item = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: .init(0.25, 0.25, 0.25)), materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: .blue, isMetallic: true)])
        box.addChild(item)
        content.add(box)
    }
    .gesture(dragThis)
  }

  var dragThis: some Gesture {
    DragGesture()
        .onChanged { value in
            print(value.translation)
            print(value.location)
            
            let dragRatio: Float = 0.0001

            box.position.x += Float(value.translation.width) * dragRatio

            box.position.y -= Float(value.translation.height) * dragRatio
        }
        .onEnded{_ in 
            box.position = [0, 0, 0]
        }
    }
}



The beauty of moving AR/VR models in 3D space of iOS RealityView using a standard 2D gesture is that you don't need to turn on a CollisionComponent, which means that heavy models are much more responsive. The disadvantage is also obvious: you need to find a balance between the speed of moving your finger on the screen and the speed of model's movement, which may be located at a considerable distance along the Z axis from the camera. This code works well (tested on 12.9" iPad):
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var position: UnitPoint = .zero
    let box = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.25))
    let ratio: Float = 0.002
    let group = Entity()
    
    var drag: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 15, coordinateSpace: .global)
            .onChanged {
                group.position.x = Float($0.translation.width + position.x) * ratio
                group.position.y = Float($0.translation.height + position.y) * -ratio
            }
            .onEnded {
                position.x += $0.translation.width
                position.y += $0.translation.height
            }
    }
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { rvc in
            group.addChild(box)
            rvc.add(group)
        }
        .gesture(drag)
    }
}


By the way, the levitation gesture in ARQuickLook is implemented in a similar way.

Thanks @Andy Jazz , I have tried it on the macOS Sequoia too and it do work but I need to change the ratio for every device with try and error, im trying to figure out a way to make this calculation of the ratio programmatically , hopefully I could :)
